# Why is my RegExp replace goes for infinite loop for this input?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm parsing some relative URLs in HTML page. But my RegExp goes for infinite loop for this HTML Document. Why is this happening as for you?

The document link: view-source:https://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/

The code with regex:

```
body = body.replace(/(?:href=(?:"|'))((?:(?:(?:\/)))?(?:(?:\.\.\/)*)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\/?)+)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,})+)?)(?:"|')/g, (a, b) => {
    return `href="${config.get('baseUrl')}api/preview?url=${new URL(b, target).href}"`;
});*/
```

This code is going for infinite loop...

Comment: You're using a global flag and are then adding more links to the body. So your own regex detects that you added `href="${config.get('baseUrl')}` and so, will go infinite. Instead of replacing the hrefs in the source, push them to an array or something so you do not change the source body while the loop runs.

Comment: How it possible @Shilly ?

Comment: I would not use a regex to parse HTML. I would place the entire body string into a documentFragment, select all the nodes from it with querySelectorAll, replace them in the fragment and finally replace the body with the fragment.

Comment: Is there any other way with this @Shilly ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use a regex? Would something like: `Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'body a' )).forEach( link => link.setAttribute( 'href', \`href="${config.get('baseUrl')}api/preview?url="someurl"` ));\` suffice? I don't really want to debug a complex regex and change it so it works after removing /g